# insert text between 2 controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want insert ":" between 2 dropdownlist in a cell.

```
tableCell.Controls.Add(DropDownListOraInizio);            
tableCell.Controls.Add(DropDownListMinutoInizio);
```

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tableCell.Controls.Add(DropDownListOraInizio);    
tableCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(":"));      
tableCell.Controls.Add(DropDownListMinutoInizio);
```

Comment: Lol, yeah for duplicate answers ;) Yours has a better timestamp though, so I deleted mine.